# Is there an injective group operation for infinite groups?

Tags: group-theory, logic, finite-groups, first-order-logic

I've been wondering if there is any infinite group $G$ with the property that its group operation $ G \times G \to G$ is injective (or some restriction of it). The reason for this is that I am asked to show that there is a first-order sentence whose models cannot be finite groups. It must also be satisfiable. I know that there is no finite axiomatization of infinite groups, so any satisfiable sentence that eliminates the possibility of finite groups must be the answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are groups with one element....

Comment: I want $G$ to be infinite.

Comment: Do you only need it to be satisfiable by "no finite group and one infinite group" or "no finite group and every infinite group"?

Comment: @Kenny Lau One is enough.

Comment: @KennyLau your second option is impossible, by the compactness theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce two axioms $ \forall x \forall y (xx = yy \Rightarrow x = y) $ and $ \exists x \forall y (x \neq yy) $ works since it says the function $ f(x) = x^2 $ on $ G $ is injective, but not surjective, which is impossible for finite groups. One can easily check that these two axioms are satisfiable for $ (\mathbb{Z}, +) $.

Answer (score 2):

No, because $e \times a = a \times e = a$.

---

The reality is much worse. For any $a \in G$, $aG = G = Ga$, so each element is repeated informally as many times as the order of the group.

---

1. Associativity: $\forall x \forall y \forall z [(x \times y) \times z = x \times (y \times z)]$
2. Identity: $\forall x [x \times e = x = e \times x]$
3. Inverse: $\forall x \exists y [x \times y = e = y \times x]$

I don't see how one can make the domain infinite without introducing a new function, so I'll introduce a unary function $S$, with the following first order axioms:

4. $\exists z \forall x [S(x) \ne z]$
5. $\forall x \forall y [x=y \iff S(x)=S(y)]$

($S$ is basically the successor function copied from Peano Arithmetic with the two axioms being from the same source.)

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you for your answer. What if we restrict it to exclude the identity element, or something similar to that? My real question is actually about a first-order sentence whose only models are infinite groups.

Comment: @mathstudent123 include your real question.

Comment: I did explain the reason for my question in the paragraph.

Comment: @mathstudent123 Still doesn't work. Take $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a$. Or by associativity, think about $(ab)c$ vs. $a(bc)$. This is not the way to solve your problem.

Comment: @mathstudent123 I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now that I think about it, introducing two axioms $\forall x \forall y (xx = yy \implies x = y) $ and $ \exists x \forall y (x \neq yy)$ should work, since it's saying that the map $f: G \to G$ given by $ x \mapsto x^2 $ is injective but not surjective, which is not possible for finite groups. Of course, $ \mathbb{Z} $ satisfies this axiom.

Comment: Hmm, it's interesting.

Comment: @mathstudent123 why don't you add it yourself as an answer?

Comment: @KennyLau will do. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mathstudent123 "Of course, $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies this axiom." Are you sure about that? What's $(-1)\cdot(-1)$? (This is easily fixed, of course, but it is technically an error.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber it isn't an error as long as you recognize that concatenation is representing the group operation :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few strategies for finding a first-order sentence modeled by no finite group but some infinite group off the top of my head.

1. Find a finite presentation $\langle R | S \rangle$ of a group $G$ with no finite quotients, and write down the first-order sentence "there exist elements $R$ satisfying the relations $S$, and one of the elements of $R$ is nonzero."
2. The above is doable but hard to do from first principles. A bit easier but probably still hard from first principles is to find a finite presentation of a group $G$ which fails to be [residually finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group), meaning there is some nonzero $g \in G$ which maps to zero in every finite quotient of $G$. Then write down the first-order sentence "there exist elements $R$ satisfying the relations $S$, and the element $g$ (expressed as a word in the generators $R$) is nonzero."
3. So far we haven't used universal quantifiers. Here is one option along these lines, which again involves finding a weird group: there exist infinite groups where all of the nonzero elements are conjugate, but this can't happen in any finite group except the trivial group and $C_2$. So we can write down "for all nonzero elements $g, h$, there exists $k$ such that $g = khk^{-1}$, and also there are at least three elements."

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly what a first-order sentence is, then here's nontrivial and pretty simple example: $$\exists X, Y \forall a, b, c, d \, ( [a^2X, b^{-1}c^2Yb] ≠ d^3).$$ Equation $[a^2X, b^{-1}c^2Yb]d^{3} = 1$ over groups with coefficients $X, Y$ in four indeterminates have solution over every finite group (by Sylow) and no solution in free group $F \langle X, Y \rangle$. Easy way to see this: apply Schutzenberger lemma — no commutator is a proper power in free group; then obvious homomorphism of free group to upper-triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices over almost any ring (e. g. $\Bbb Z / 2$) detects nontriviality of commutator .

Comment: Well, this reads «there exists a choice of coefficients such that equation becomes unsolvable»; in every finite group it is wrong, while in free group it is true, which is (I assume) what OP wants.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I misread your answer. (Unfortunately my downvote is locked in - I can't change it unless the answer is edited.)

Comment: Nevermind. Nevertheless, I think I should edit it for clarity.